# add and retrieve data from datagrid, WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to add data on button click to a datagrid. Suppose a datagrid with 3 headers, namely ITEM, QUANTITY, PRICE. Now when a user click for first time i shld get data in first row like this.

```
1   1   1
```

then on second click the total data will be

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
```

and so on

```
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
n   n   n
```

and when i click a button say to array, I should get datagrid data in arraylist. Is this possible in WPF?? I have done this already in web applications using jquery and backend methods. Anyhow I hope this will be easy in WPF also. I have searched net but all examples seem to be complex with data binding, I dont want to do data binding, and want to go with tht simple way which i tried to explain above, hope its clear.

Comment: Well IMHO `DataBinding` is the simplest way in WPF and SL.^^

Comment: Yes DataBinding would be the simplest way to do this. Otherwise you have to write your own logic to update the datagrid every time you change the data. Also with databinding, it means that you would have a collection bound to the itemssource property of the datagrid. You could perhaps very easily call a ToArray() or ToList() method on the collection to extract your results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with the two commenters, databinding is the the way to do this, I know it looks quite complex at first but once you get a nice library of converters and commands together it can be reused again and again, a simple data binding example from above would look like this.

XAML, create a new project and in the main window paste this code, all it does is add a data grid with 3 columns and a button that will add new rows. Please note that the data context of this window is set to itself, that means properties on the class MainWindow will be exposed with {Binding} by default.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="274" Width="497" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Field1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Field2}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Field3}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the code behind for MainWindow, here I've created 2 properties that we can bind to, one is Items which contains an array of what will appear as rows and the other is a command that can be called to add another row.

The ObservableCollection here has methods that tell the binding engine when rows are changed so you don't have to bother updating the grid yourself.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Item>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public SimpleCommand AddCommand
        {
            get { return (SimpleCommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AddCommand", typeof(SimpleCommand), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            AddCommand = new SimpleCommand(para =>
            {
                string nextNumber = Items.Count.ToString();
                Items.Add(new Item() { Field1 = nextNumber, Field2 = nextNumber, Field3 = nextNumber });
            });
        }
    }
```

The Item class, this is just a really simple class that has 3 properties that match your data grid, field1, 2 & 3 the dependency properties here also mean that you don't have to bother updating the grid yourself when data changes.

```
public class Item : DependencyObject
{
    public string Field1
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Field1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Field1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Field1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Field1", typeof(string), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Field2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Field2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Field2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Field2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Field2", typeof(string), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Field3
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Field3Property); }
        set { SetValue(Field3Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Field3Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Field3", typeof(string), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

And finally the command class, this can be reused over and over in all of your projects to link something to code behind.

```
public class SimpleCommand : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public SimpleCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute == null ? parmeter => { return true; } : canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }
    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i did not mention about mysql, anyway, I still want to run away from data binding as i dont want to view data from db, instead i want to add data manually on button click at runtime, i.e the values can come from user input also, later on other key press i want to insert data in db at that point of time, till then just the user should be able to add or delete data only from the datagrid. Hope understud, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

To show how easy it is to achieve this with DataBinding, I quickly knocked up this little app. This took me about 10 minutes, but more experienced programmers with Resharper and other tools can pretty much knock this up in a couple of minutes.

Here is my InventoryItemViewModel.cs

```
public class InventoryItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _itemid;

    public int ItemId
    {
        get { return _itemid; }
        set { _itemid = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemId"); }
    }

    private int _qty;

    public int Qty
    {
        get { return _qty; }
        set { _qty = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Qty"); }
    }
    private int _price;

    public int Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set { _price = value; this.OnPropertyChanged("Price"); }
    }

}
```

As you can see there's not much to it, just your 3 properties. The magic that enables the easy UI updates is because I implement ViewModelBase.

Here is ViewModelBase.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Abstract base to consolidate common functionality of all ViewModels
/// </summary>
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can pretty much copy this class to all your WPF projects and use this as it is.

Here is the viewmodel for my main window: MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.InventoryCollection = new ObservableCollection<InventoryItemViewModel>();
        this.AddItemCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) => this.AddItem());
        this.GetItemListCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) => this.GetInventoryItemList());
    }

    public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand GetItemListCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<InventoryItemViewModel> InventoryCollection { get; private set; }

    private void AddItem()
    {
        // get maxid in collection
        var maxid = InventoryCollection.Count;
        // if collection is not empty get the max id (which is the same as count in this case but whatever)
        if (maxid > 0) maxid = InventoryCollection.Max(x => x.ItemId);

        InventoryCollection.Add(new InventoryItemViewModel
        {
            ItemId = ++maxid,
            Price = maxid,
            Qty = maxid
        });
    }

    private List<InventoryItemViewModel> GetInventoryItemList()
    {
        return this.InventoryCollection.ToList();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an ObservableCollection of InventoryItemViewModels. This is the collection that I bind to from my UI. It is imperative that you use an ObservableCollection instead of a List or array. To make my buttons work, I define ICommand properties which are then bound to my buttons in the UI. I use a DelegateCommand class to redirect action to the respective private Methods.

Here is the DelegateCommand.cs, this is another class that you can just include in your WPF projects and trust it to work.

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Action to be performed when this command is executed
    /// </summary>
    private Action<object> executionAction;

    /// <summary>
    /// Predicate to determine if the command is valid for execution
    /// </summary>
    private Predicate<object> canExecutePredicate;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the DelegateCommand class.
    /// The command will always be valid for execution.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The delegate to call on execution</param>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the DelegateCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The delegate to call on execution</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The predicate to determine if command is valid for execution</param>
    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        this.executionAction = execute;
        this.canExecutePredicate = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when CanExecute is changed
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the delegate backing this DelegateCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">parameter to pass to predicate</param>
    /// <returns>True if command is valid for execution</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecutePredicate == null ? true : this.canExecutePredicate(parameter);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the delegate backing this DelegateCommand
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">parameter to pass to delegate</param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown if CanExecute returns false</exception>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (!this.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The command is not valid for execution, check the CanExecute method before attempting to execute.");
        }
        this.executionAction(parameter);
    }
```

And my UI code on my MainWindow.xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ctlDefs="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=GetItemListCommand}" Content="Get Item List" />
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=AddItemCommand}" Content="Add Item" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InventoryCollection}" />
</StackPanel>
```

To glue it all together, I override the App.xaml.cs OnStartUp Method.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var mainvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        var window = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = mainvm
        };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing you were writing that while I wrote mine lol, they're almost identical

Comment: Yeah probably lol! It took me ages to post the answer, had some mad lag going on!

Comment: My database is mysql :(, can this be achieved

Comment: You didn't mention in your question about databases. How does the database interact with your problem?

Comment: There are a few methods to read and write data to a mysql database. Here is a link that shows how to using Entity Framework. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/09/getting-mysql-work-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: Sorry i did not mention about mysql, anyway, I still want to run away from data binding as i dont want to view data from db, instead i want to add data manually on button click at runtime, i.e the values can come from user input also, later on other key press i want to insert data in db at that point of time, till then just the user should be able to add or delete data only from the datagrid. Hope understud, thanks for your efforts